# It is necessary for the condition to work on the basis of a condition with a rollback of time by several bars

Tags: pine-script

I would like to compare certain mathematical conditions on historical data for research purposes. But I need the new condition to work based on the results of the previous calculation with the rollback of time a few bars back.

Simply put, I need to put a label on the historical chart so that the following conditions take it into account.

I don't understand how to do it. Is this really possible in pine 5?

simple example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("")

condition_1 = close > close[20] // just for example, don't look for logic
condition_2 = close < close[5] // just for example, don't look for logic

bool done = false
if condition_2 == true and condition_1[-10] == true // -10 in square brackets to understand the meaning, I understand that this is a bug in Pine, but how to solve this problem?
    done

plotchar(done)
plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look back 10 bars, you should use `[10]` instead of `[-10]`

```
//@version=5
indicator("")

condition_1 = close > close[20] // just for example, don't look for logic
condition_2 = close < close[5] // just for example, don't look for logic

bool done = false
if condition_2 == true and condition_1[10] == true 
    done

plotchar(done)
plot(close)
```

Comment: Bjorn Mistiaen, thank you very much for your reply. You are right, but in my case it is necessary that I receive this signal earlier. I think it will be possible to solve this problem by writing closed positions to an array and on the basis of the array, do the calculation and put labels for subsequent conditions. And I'm thinking more and more about switching to Python 

Comment: those. the "done" condition, I should get 10 bar earlier if we consider our example.

Comment: That would mean you'd like to look into the future. This cannot be done. It for sure won't work on live data.

Comment: I need to analyze only the last 400 bars, and put labels for further calculations. I don't understand why it's so hard to do in a Pine 5.